# pgf input not showing in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I've extracted a matlotlib to a .pgf file. I'm now trying to include it in my beamer presentation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\mode<presentation>{}
\title{Foo}
\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
   foo!
   \input{baz.pgf}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I then run either "pdflatex pres.tex" or "xelatex pres.tex". I get a pdf of the slide, but the image does not display.

Here is the actual pgf file I'm attempting to include: http://pastebin.com/eJAEJEwg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the size of the figure. If you look in the PGF file, near the top of the code part is the line

```
\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{22.050000in}{14.075000in}}%
\pgfusepath{use as bounding box, clip}%
```

indicating that the figure is going to be 22x14 inches in size, way bigger than the Beamer frame. If you put the figure in a `scalebox` then you can see it on the slide, but there seems to be a lot of whitespace around the figure. I'm not sure how to get rid of it, you'll have to investigate, maybe starting here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11847260/2449192

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\mode<presentation>{}
\title{Foo}
\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
   foo!
   \scalebox{0.1}{\input{test.pgf}}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]